# Mock Grails configurations in Integration test cases

Tags: grails, grails-controller

How to mock Grails configurations in Integration test cases?

Consider following scenario

**MyController.groovy**

```
def save() {
    baseLink = Holders.getFlatConfig()["grails.test.base.link"]
    if (!baseLink) {
        response.status = HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value
        respond([message: "Configuration not found."])
        return
    }
    // Some Code
}
```

**MyControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy**

```
def save() {
    baseLink = Holders.getFlatConfig()["grails.test.base.link"]
    if (!baseLink) {
        response.status = HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value
        respond([message: "Configuration not found."])
        return
    }
    // Some Code
}


def setup() {
    //Some Setup Code
    //Update configuration
    grailsApplication.config["grails.test.base.link"] = true
}

void "Configuration not found"() {
    when: ""
    myController.save()

    then: "Configuration not found"
    controller.response.json["message"] == "Configuration not found."
    controller.response.status == HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value
}    

void "Configuration found"() {
    when: ""
    myController.save()

    then: "Configuration found"
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know why you want to mock the grails application in an integration test, my suggestion would be to use DI of `grailsApplication`. Is there any reason why you use `baseLink = Holders.getFlatConfig()["grails.test.base.link"]` instead of `grailsApplication.config.grails.test.base.link` ? What grails version are you using?

When using grailsApplication as a dependency the controller, you can inject it in the test:

```
def setup() {
  myController.grailsApplication = [config: [grails: [test: [base: [link: true]]]]]
}

void "Configuration found"() {
  when: ""
  myController.save()

  then: "Configuration found"
  //some code
}
```